# Reading And Writing to text file

Tags: java, io

I've written this code to read in a file and then ask for a mark, for each name in the file. And if the mark is over 40 its a pass and below is a fail and writes each name to the corresponding file. But I get an error at line 27 which: `while(namesFile.hasNext()` here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestResults {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String errs = "";
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            try (
                    Scanner namesFile = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt"));

                    PrintWriter passFile = new PrintWriter("Pass.txt");
                    PrintWriter failFile = new PrintWriter("Fail.txt");) {

                while (namesFile.hasNext()) {
                    try {
                        String tempLine = namesFile.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Please Enter Mark For " + tempLine + " : ");
                        int mark = k.nextInt();
                        if (mark >= 40) {
                            passFile.println(tempLine + " " + mark + "%");
                        } else {
                            failFile.println(tempLine + " " + mark);
                        }
                    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                        String valueStr = namesFile.next();
                        errs += "\n\t" + valueStr;
                    } finally {
                        namesFile.close();
                        passFile.close();
                        failFile.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } // Checks to see if file is there.
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: why is there try{ try ( ?

Comment: make your code correct.

Comment: Try `while(namesFile.hasNextLine() )` ...

Comment: The error code is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1115)
 at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1713)
 at java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine(Scanner.java:1545)
 at TestResults.main(TestResults.java:16)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: I guess you'll have to remove the `;` in `PrintWriter failFile = new PrintWriter("Fail.txt");) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TestResults {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner namesFile;
    PrintWriter passFile;
    PrintWriter failFile;


     String errs = "";
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        try {
                namesFile = new Scanner(new File("D:/Names.txt"));

                passFile = new PrintWriter("D:/Pass.txt");
                failFile = new PrintWriter("D:/Fail.txt");



                try {
                    while (namesFile.hasNext()) {
                    String tempLine = namesFile.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please Enter Mark For " + tempLine + " : ");
                    int mark = k.nextInt();
                    if (mark >= 40) {
                        passFile.println(tempLine + " " + mark + "%");
                    } else {
                        failFile.println(tempLine + " " + mark);
                    }
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                    String valueStr = namesFile.next();
                    errs += "\n\t" + valueStr;
                } finally {
                    namesFile.close();
                    passFile.close();
                    failFile.close();
                }



        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }



    } // Checks to see if file is there.
    catch (Exception e) {

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What is your improvement here?

Comment: in SomeSickJoke's code the namesFile is not in the scope of while(). That is the error. And he wrote the final block inside the while loop. It makes the file reads single line and close the stream. so 2nd line cannot be read. I put while loop inside try block. And it works properly.

Comment: Yes it is. It is a "try with resources". See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: The finally block is a good catch, though! Didn't see it. Maybe you can add the try-with-resources to your solution, and it will earn you a +1 from me :)